# 2d array formatting issue. I am trying to tab my columns with /t but that just causes my rows to disappear

Tags: java

I have a 2D array with 3 columns. When it prints, I need it to tab. I am using the `/t` and `/n` for next line but it is displaying in a straight line across instead of staying in rows. I will put my code in. How do I fix it?

```
package presidnetssort;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

``import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.*;
    public class PresidentsSort 
    {



        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
        {
            //Create scanner object to read the file.
            Scanner x = new Scanner(new File("PresidentsGrades.txt"));

            //Create a string array to hold the data from the file.
            String[][] a = new String[44][3];

            //Create a loop to to add the file data to the array.
            for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                a[i][0]=x.next();
                a[i][1]=x.next();
                a[i][2]=x.next();
           }
            //Call the sorting methods. I am commenting them out. Uncomment     them one at a time to use them.
            //sortNames(a);
            //sortCourses(a);
            //sortGrades(a);
            //Call the print method to print the a array.
            print(a);
            StdOut.printf("/t,/t/n",a);

        }

    public static void sortNames(String[][] a)
    {


        Arrays.toString(a);
        StdOut.printf("/t",a);
    }
    public static void sortCourses(String[][] a)
    {

        Arrays.toString(a);
        print(a);
    }
    public static void sortGrades(String[][] a)
    {

        Arrays.toString(a);
        print(a);
    }
     static void print(String[][] a)
     {
            for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                for (int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++) 
                    System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
                 StdOut.printf("/t,/t/n",a);
            }
      }
     }
```

my output displays as:
Wasington Algorithm 98 /t,/t/nAdams Math 89 /t,/t/nJefferson Java 85 /t,/t/nMadison C# 83 /t,/t/nMonroe Web 88 /t,/t/nAdams Algorithm 81 /t,/t/n

When I take the formatting out and do not use StdOut.print, it prints in rows as it should but not tabbed, like this:

Wasington Algorithm 98 
Adams Math 89 
Jefferson Java 85 
Madison C# 83 
Monroe Web 88 
Adams Algorithm 81 
Jackson Java 78 
Buren C# 75 
Harrison Computers 45 
Tyler Algorithm 73 
Polk Java 68 
Taylor Algorithm 88 
Fillmore Web 93 
Pierce Math 56 
Buchanan Algorithm 77 
Lincoln Algorithm 99 
Johnson C# 76 
Grant Algorithm 92 
Hayes Web 76 
Garfield Computers 66 
Arthur Web 77 
Cleveland Java 88 
Harrison Algorithm 75 
Cleveland C# 91 
McKinley Algorithm 100 
Roosevelt Web 79 
Taft C# 86 
Wilson C# 84 
Harding Web 67 
Coolidge Math 67 
Hoover History 76 
Roosevelt History 84 
Truman Math 83 
Eisenhower History 100 
Kennedy Java 95 
Johnson Algorithm 56 
Nixon History 23 
Ford History 78 
Carter Math 55 
Regan Algorithm 99 
Bush Algorithm 89 
Clinton History 45 
Bush Math 75 
Obama History 13

Answer (score 1):

The tab and new line characters are `\t` and `\n` respectively, change

```
StdOut.printf("/t,/t/n",a);
```

to something like

```
StdOut.printf("\t,\t\n",a);
```

and

```
StdOut.printf("/t",a);
```

to

```
StdOut.printf("\t",a);
```

and so on...